# Trying to display array of images, code returns iphone to home screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, image, ios

Here is the problem code:

The code is to display an array of images which can then be scrolled through.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *photos = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:   
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"Event.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"default.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"LittleLogoImage.png"],
                        nil] retain];      // TODO – fill with your photos

    // note that the view contains a UIScrollView in aScrollView

    int i=0;
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    for ( NSString *image in photos )
    {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[photos objectAtIndex:i]];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

        imageView.frame = CGRectMake( imageView.frame.size.width * i++, 0, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height);

        [aScrollView addSubview:imageView];
        width = imageView.frame.size.width;
        height = imageView.frame.size.height;

        [imageView release];
    }
    aScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width*i, height);
    aScrollView.delegate = self;
}
```

Any ideas?

> [Session started at 2011-05-07
>   22:46:47 +0100.] 2011-05-07
>   22:46:49.314 ALPHA[1171:207] load01
>   2011-05-07 22:47:13.749
>   ALPHA[1171:207] 2 2011-05-07
>   22:47:13.751 ALPHA[1171:207] dealloc01
>   2011-05-07 22:47:13.755
>   ALPHA[1171:207] load02 2011-05-07
>   22:47:19.791 ALPHA[1171:207] 4
>   2011-05-07 22:47:19.792
>   ALPHA[1171:207] dealloc02 2011-05-07
>   22:47:19.795 ALPHA[1171:207] -[UIImage
>   length]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x4b20f60 2011-05-07
>   22:47:19.797 ALPHA[1171:207] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[UIImage length]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x4b20f60'
>   *** Call stack at first throw: (  0   CoreFoundation
>   0x00dca5a9 **exceptionPreprocess + 185
>     1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x00f1e313 objc_exception_throw + 44
>     2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00dcc0bb -[NSObject(NSObject)
>   doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187  3
>
>   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00d3b966 __*forwarding*** + 966     4
>   CoreFoundation
>   0x00d3b522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
>     5   UIKit
>   0x003e3568 _UIImageAtPath + 36    6
>   ALPHA
>   0x000037fd -[PhotosView viewDidLoad] +
>   597   7   UIKit
>   0x0036a089 -[UIViewController view] +
>   179   8   ALPHA
>   0x00002af3 -[ALPHAViewController
>   displayView:] + 500   9   ALPHA
>   0x00002707 -[ALPHAAppDelegate
>   displayView:] + 60    10  ALPHA
>   0x00002cdd -[View2 viewPhotos:] + 99
>     11  UIKit
>   0x002ba4fd -[UIApplication
>   sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
>     12  UIKit
>   0x0034a799 -[UIControl
>   sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67     13 
>   UIKit
>   0x0034cc2b -[UIControl(Internal)
>   _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527   14  UIKit
>   0x0034b7d8 -[UIControl
>   touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458    15 
>   UIKit
>   0x002deded -[UIWindow
>   _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567  16  UIKit
>   0x002bfc37 -[UIApplication sendEvent:]
>   + 447     17  UIKit                               0x002c4f2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent +
>   7576  18  GraphicsServices
>   0x01722992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
>     19  CoreFoundation
>   0x00dab944
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION**
>   + 52  20  CoreFoundation                      0x00d0bcf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
>     21  CoreFoundation
>   0x00d08f83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979   22 
>   CoreFoundation
>   0x00d08840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
>     23  CoreFoundation
>   0x00d08761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97    24
>   GraphicsServices
>   0x017211c4 GSEventRunModal + 217  25 
>   GraphicsServices
>   0x01721289 GSEventRun + 115   26  UIKit
>   0x002c8c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
>     27  ALPHA
>   0x000026a8 main + 102     28  ALPHA
>   0x00002639 start + 53 )

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

Thanks again,

Jack

Comment: It crashed, right? Give us the console output and the stacktrace, please.

Comment: Also, if you can step through it and tell us which line causes the crash that would help a ton.

Comment: Looks like there are a few good explanations below. If it's working, you should accept an answer. If not, please provide more information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for ( NSString *image in photos )
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[photos objectAtIndex:i]];
    ...
```

This is your problem.  You have an `NSString` and a `UIImage` named the same thing.  When you redeclare your `NSString` as a `UIImage`, you are confusing your the `forin` loop.  The loop seems to still think that you have an `NSString`, when in reality, you have a `UIImage`.  So our first step is to try replacing that code with this code instead:

```
for ( NSString *imageName in photos )
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    ...
```

However, that code won't work either.  Fortunately, your `images` array already stores `UIImages`, so your don't need an `NSString` at all!  Thus you can replace the first three lines of your loop with this:

```
for ( UIImage *image in photos )
{
    ...
```

That's it!  You don't need your `UIImage *image = ...` line at all since it's created in the parentheses.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

In `photos` you already store UIImage objects. Why you trying in cycle loop crete `UIImage` from `UIImage`?

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[photos objectAtIndex:i]];
```

You should do like this:

```
UIImage *image = [photos objectAtIndex:i];
```

Comment: That seems to be the issue, probably the +imageNamed method wants to get the length of the string, which then crashes the app, because UIImage does not respond to -length.

Comment: You're right. I like such situations when we can a get a little nit of understanding how framework methods works.

Answer (score 0):

photos is an NSArray of UIImages yes you're enumerating it as strings?

```
for ( NSString *image in photos )
```

should be:

```
for ( UIImage *image in photos )
    {
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

        imageView.frame = CGRectMake( imageView.frame.size.width * i++, 0, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height);

        [aScrollView addSubview:imageView];
        width = imageView.frame.size.width;
        height = imageView.frame.size.height;

        [imageView release];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, changed it but it still crashes :/

Comment: Actually, it doesn't matter (only warnings could appear in some situations). In objective-c all types will be checked at runtime. Moreover, `for (id image in photos)` works slightly faster. It was on one of performance lectures at WWDC'2010.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( UIImage *img in photos ){

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];

...... // write something

}
```