# Unrecognised selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiimage

I got a problem that I don't understand even after reading a few threads

This is the error i get:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x576f8f0'
```

This is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *filePath = [[self documentsPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@""];

    NSFileManager *imagesFileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    imagesArr = [[imagesFileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:filePath error:nil]filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.jpg'"]];

    arryList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[imagesArr copy]];//display text
    imagesList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];//display image

    NSString *docPath = [self documentsPath];

    for (NSString *anImagePath in arryList) {
        anImagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",docPath,anImagePath];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:anImagePath];
        if (image)
            [imagesList addObject:image];

        NSLog(@"%@", anImagePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: The error says that you are trying to call the method `length` of an `UIImage`, which doesn't implement it. Try to find someplace else in your code where this method is being called.

Comment: try logging - see how far it gets through this method before it crashes

Comment: You should have an exception traceback in the console log (unless you're running on the broken iOS 5) that will point you to where the error is.  Somewhere you're calling `length` with a pointer that is actually pointing at a UIImage (even if it is typed as something else).  Sometimes this occurs due to failure to retain an object, but other times it's simply due to assigning the wrong value to something.

Comment: You shouldn't modify the loop variable `anImagePath` inside its loop.  It may seem to work, but it's bad style and it's confusing.

Answer (score 6):

You aren't the one calling `length` on a `UIImage`, the `forin` loop is.  This is because the objects in `arrayList` are actually images, but the loop thinks they are strings because you have essentially type-casted them that way with `NSString *anImagePath`.  Try changing your code from this:

```
for (NSString *anImagePath in arryList) {
    anImagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",docPath,anImagePath];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:anImagePath];
    if (image)
        [imagesList addObject:image];

    NSLog(@"%@", anImagePath);
}
```

to this:

```
for (UIImage *image in arryList) {
    if (image)
        [imagesList addObject:image];

    NSLog(@"%@", anImagePath);
}
```

I'm guessing that you are already storing `UIImage` objects in the array.  For more reference, visit [Trying to display array of images, code returns iphone to home screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924111/trying-to-display-array-of-images-code-returns-iphone-to-home-screen/5927620#5927620).

Comment: NSFileManager's `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:` will return array of NSString. ([Ref](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) . In that case `arryList` will also be definitely array of NSString. So it won't solve the problem.

Comment: It return array of strings instead of images

Comment: Hmmm...why are you changing the replacing the fetched `arrayList` with new image paths?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here's another go at it.  Hopefully this time I understand your problem better.  `forin` has problems when you try to modify its collection, so maybe doing this will help.

Change this:

```
for (NSString *anImagePath in arryList) {
    anImagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",docPath,anImagePath];
```

To this:

```
for (NSString *anImagePath in imagesArr) {
    [arrayList setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",docPath,anImagePath]
                 atIndex:[imagesArr indexOfObject:anImagePath]];
```

This way, we're cycling through a copy of the array we modify, not the array we modify itself.  However, this is rather bad code (creating `arrayList` as a copy of `imagesArr` and then trashing all its objects), so we could try the following instead.

Change this:

```
arrayList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[imagesArr copy]];
```

To this:

```
arrayList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Then in our `forin` loop, change this:

```
for (NSString *anImagePath in imagesArr) {
    [arrayList setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",docPath,anImagePath]
                 atIndex:[imagesArr indexOfObject:anImagePath]];
```

To this:

```
for (NSString *anImagePath in imagesArr) {
    [arrayList addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",docPath,anImagePath]];
```

Hope this works better!

Comment: thanks for spending time looking through my code and answering me

Comment: @user1063318 did this work?  If so, could you please vote the answer up and click the hollow checkmark next to it?  This will show others that this is the correct solution.